# How do you get Apache to provide details on a 403 response code?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cron

We are having a problem with one of our WordPress Web sites that appears to be caused by Apache.  The problem is that the internal WordPress cron (wp-cron.php) is not being run.  Normally this internal cron is not driven by the server’s cron but by an internal process that is fired when someone visits the site.  Those visits do not cause the  wp-cron.php program to be run directly but instead the visits cause a program to be run and submits a HTTP POST that looks like:

[Apache Log entry with 403 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgBN.jpg)

in the Apache log.   These POST are being rejected by Apache with a 403 status code.

In order to work around this we are using www.easycron.com to submit request to the web site which are not rejected as shown by this log entry.

[Apache log entry for Easycron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PTy.jpg)

This would seem to imply that the problem is not with folder or file permissions which appear to be in order anyway.

So here finally is the question.  Is there a way to get Apache to give us more detailed information on why a POST is being rejected with a 403 status code?

Comment: Have you checked the Php error log? There is likely some more information there

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not seeing any errors in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't find anyway to get Apache to provide details on the 403 response code I was able to narrow down the problem by modifying the HTTP request until the problem went away.  The request was being rejected because WordPress places the site's domain name in the User Agent which in this case was shimmyshack.com.  This particular domain name was being rejected because it contains the work "hack" in it. a word, among many others, that our Internet Service Provider (ISP) deemed a threat.  The ISP eventually removed the word "hack" from this list solving the problem.  They said it was no longer considered a threat but offered no explanation how it could have been a threat in the first place.